# data-role="Content" width is not changing with Orientation

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation

I am developing an Android application using PhoneGap. when I change my emulator orientation from portrait to landscape, Header and Footer of page are getting changes in width but the `data-role="content"` block is having same width width as it is portrait mode.

How to solve this issue.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is a uncommon problem on some android devices. This is my fix:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page, #page .content {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Add here every page your application is using. Unfortunately I cant remember web source for this fix.